# Keras,models.add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'layer'

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm classifying digits of the MNIST dataset using a simple feed forward neural net with Keras. So I execute the code below.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/data', one_hot=True)

# Path to Computation graphs
LOGDIR = './graphs_3'

# start session
sess = tf.Session()

#Hyperparameters
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
EPOCHS = 10

# Layers
HL_1 = 1000
HL_2 = 500

# Other Parameters
INPUT_SIZE = 28*28
N_CLASSES = 10

model = Sequential
model.add(Dense(HL_1, input_dim=(INPUT_SIZE,), activation="relu"))
#model.add(Activation(activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(HL_2, activation="relu"))
#model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.9))
model.add(Dense(N_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    optimizer="Adam",
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=['accuracy'])



# one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=10)

model.fit(
    x=mnist.train.images, 
    y=mnist.train.labels, 
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)


score = model.evaluate(
    x=mnist.test.images,
    y=mnist.test.labels)

print("score = ", score)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=(INPUT_SIZE,), activation="relu"))
   TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'layer'
```

The syntax is exactly as shown in the keras docs. I am using keras 2.0.9, so I don't think it's a version control problem. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems perfect indeed....

But I noticed you're not creating "an instance" of a sequential model, your using the class name instead:

```
#yours: model = Sequential 
#correct:
model = Sequential()
```

Since the methods in a class are always declared containing `self` as the first argument, calling the methods without an instance will probably require the instance as the first argument (which is `self`).

The method's definition is `def add(self,layer,...):`